# How to set a resource property

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I have a Sling [`Resource`](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource.html) object. What is the best way to set or update its property?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It depends on the Sling version:

**Sling >= 2.3.0 (since CQ 5.6)**

Adapt your resource to [`ModifiableValueMap`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ModifiableValueMap.html), use its `put` method and commit the resource resolver:

```
ModifiableValueMap map = resource.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
map.put("property", "value");
resource.getResourceResolver().commit();
```

**Sling < 2.3.0 (CQ 5.5 and earlier)**

Adapt your resource to [`PersistableValueMap`](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/PersistableValueMap.html), use its `put` and `save` methods:

```
PersistableValueMap map = resource.adaptTo(PersistableValueMap.class);
map.put("property", "value");
map.save();
```

**JCR API**

You may also adapt the resource to `Node` and use the JCR API to change property. However, it's a good idea to stick to one abstraction layer and in this case we somehow break the `Resource` abstraction provided by Sling.

```
Node node = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
node.setProperty("property", "value");
node.getSession().save();
```

Comment: How to specify the type of value? 
map.put("property", "value") sets the type as String. How to customize the type while using put() method!

Answer (score 4):

As many developers are not fond of using `Node API`. You can also use ValueMap and ModifiableValueMap APIs to read and update property respectively.

**Read Value through ValueMap**

```
ValueMap valueMap = resource.getValueMap();
valueMap.get("yourProperty", String.class);
```

**Write/Modify property through ModifiableValueMap**

```
ModifiableValueMap modifiableValueMap = resource.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
modifiableValueMap.put("NewProperty", "Your Value");  //write
modifiableValueMap.put("OldProperty", "Updated Value"); // Modify
```

After writing property to a node, save these values by committing the 'resourceResolver'

> You'll need system/service user for **admin resourceResolver**.
>
> Go through [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/security-service-users.html#ServiceUsersandMappings) documentation for more info about service user.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working in publish. But if user logged-In `as admin` it will work.

```
ModifiableValueMap map = resource.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
map.put("property", "value");
resource.getResourceResolver().commit();
```