# Setting metadata to DAM assets

Tags: aem, dam

How can I set new metadata to all my existing DAM assets(5000 assets) in my AEM production author.

AEM Environment : AEM 6.1

Comment: Can you give example of meta data you wabt to add? Also is this part of asset upload or are these existing assets?

Comment: As the question is not clear, what MIME type of asset metadata you want to update, have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653070/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-set-metadata-of-an-asset) it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this metadata programmatically.
Select all assets:
`resourceResolver.findResources("/jcr:root/content/dam//element(*,dam:Asset)", "xpath")`
and for each asset add required metadata.

Nowadays in AEM standard de-facto is [groovyconsole](https://github.com/OlsonDigital/aem-groovy-console) for all tasks like migration changes/repository updates etc. If you don't want to install it on production env you still can create java class which will be executed on bundle start or you can create servlet which you can call manually.

**Note**: in groovyconsole you can use standard java code without any changes if you don't want to learn groovy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set metadata based on the image, I would recommend using the CSV Asset Importer by installing the ACS AEM Tools package. Here you would need to provide the metadata for each asset in an excel.

For more information, please refer to https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/csv-asset-importer/index.html